# Node.js redirect user to another page once function inside POST request is executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a nodejs code where the user initially is in the `localhost:3000/index` once the code starts, the page `/index` has a form, once user clicks submit button he gets redirected to another page `localhost:3000/process` there is a POST request (in `script.js` file) that sends those data to server, then the `POST` request on the `server` side needs to `execute a function`, only once the function (which is inside the POST request is executed)then I would like the user to be redirected to another page `localhost:3000/done`

`res.render('done')` and `res.redirect('/done')` at the end of the post request are not working..

I have tried many things, but still not able to be redirected once the function inside the `post` request is executed.

the structure of my project is like this:

```
public folder structure:
   js_folder:
    script.js

routes folder:

  index.js
  process.js
  done.js

views folder:
  index.ejs
  process.ejs
  done.ejs

app.js file

      ******      *******        ******* ***      ****
```

this how the process.js file looks like:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    
    /*once the user clicks on submit button (in the localhost:3000/index page) he is redirected  */

    router.get('/process', async (req, res) => {
// this process.ejs is showing 'please wait until function is executed'
      res.render('process')
    });
    router.post('/process', async (req, res) => {
    // getting data sent by the form
    var data = req.body;
    
    const functionOne = async function firstFunction() { 
    //do something
    }
    const secondFunction = async () => {
        const update = await functionOne()
        console.log('something is done');
    // now I would like to redirect the user to the 'localhost:3000/done'
    
      }
      secondFunction();
    });
```

/****** *************************** **********/

```
the script.js file:

    function launchTerraform() {
      
        var data = {
          instances: document.getElementById('firstName').value,
          region: document.getElementById('lastName').value
        }
       
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 && this.responseText) {
           
          } 
        }
          xhr.open('POST', '/provision', true)
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
          xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
          
         window.location.href = '/process'
        }
```

Comment: It seems that you want to (1) display a message "Please wait until the function is executed" and (2) redirect the user after the function has been executed. An HTTP response can *either* display some HTML *or* send a redirect header, in other words, (1) or (2) but not both.

Comment: I have tried to change it by creating a new route, so instead of using router.post('/process', ...) I changed it to router.post('/loading', ...) so I have only one get request for  /process instead of having to requests (post and get) for the same route ('/process'). but still the same issue, render/ redirect at the end of the post request are not working

Comment: Remove `window.location.href = '/process'`, and direct to your intended page when the XHR is complete. Going to /process removes your ability to act based on the response of the post.

Comment: I tried, I removed the window.location.href = '/process' and added res.redirect inside the secondFunction() (added it as well at the end of the post request) but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server function could simply send an empty response (with status 200) after the asynchronous function has completed.

```js
router.post('/process', async (req, res) => {
  var data = req.body;
  const functionOne = async function firstFunction() { 
    //do something asynchronous with data
  }
  await functionOne();
  res.end();
});
```

Then your client script could tell the user to wait before making an XHR to `/process` and perform the redirect to `/done` after the status 200 response has come in.

```js
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    window.location.href = '/done';
  }
};
document.getElementById("some_placeholder").textContent = "Please wait ...";
xhr.open('POST', '/process', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only send one response.

A workaround for this is using [express-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash) to display the "please wait" message, and then once it is done you can use your 1 response to redirect the user to the "/done" page by doing `res.redirect("/done")`. But that requires you use passport and cookie-parser.